# Why is KivyMD apk applicaion closing right after opening?

Tags: python, kivy, apk, buildozer

So I created a simple UI calculator using KivyMD and was trying to convert it to APK with buildozer (following a tutorial), on colab, so I could try and run it on my phone. But when I open the App, it closes about half seconds later, after showing the loading screen. There weren't any errors during the build, either. I'm extrmmely conused, and I have no idea what to do right now.

To create the apk, I uploaded my main.py file to google coab, and then simply ran all these commands. The only thing I changed was the title in the spec file. Here are all the commands I ran-
[image]

And after the build, I got my apk from the bin file-

[image]

What did i do wrong? Were there any steps I missed? If so, please help me with this.Thanks!

Comment: Connect your phone to your PC (with a USB cable), then run: `buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat > my_log.txt`. Then have a look at `my_log.txt` for hints.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm kinda new to this. Run it where exactly?

Comment: The same place you ran `buildozer` before.

Comment: Oh yeah nvm, apparenty the new version of kivymd needs "pillow" in the requirements. It works by adding that.

Answer (score 0):

Including the "pillow" library int he requirements of the spec file seems to work!